# From graph to time series

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, neural-networks, time-series

Let's consider the time series:

```
seria={38, 30, 23, 23, 14, 27, 21, 37, 25, 10, 24, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6, 13, 14, 6, 11, 3, 3, 15, 8, 17, 31, 56, 28, 9, 9, 52, 43, 11, 4, 15, 10,7, 10, 7, 7, 10, 12, 35, 40, 13, 13, 5, 10}

fig1=ListPlot[seria -> Range[Length[seria]], Filling -> Axis]
```

We are looking for the visibility of each peak:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 lseria = Length[seria];
 pary = {};
 Do[
  kmax = n;
  q2 = seria[[kmax]];
  
  If[IntegerQ[n/500] == True, Print[n]];
  
  Do[
   kmin = p;
   q1 = seria[[kmin]];
   q3 = Take[seria, {kmin + 1, kmax - 1}];
   If[
    kmin + 1 == kmax,
    AppendTo[pary, {kmin, kmax}],
    If[
     Min[{q1, q2}] >= Max[q3],
     AppendTo[pary, {kmin, kmax}],
     If[
      Max[{q1, q2}] >= Max[q3],
      If[q1 < q2,
       temp = {};
       
       Table[
        q5 = seria[[kmin + k]];
        If[
         q5 > q1,
         AppendTo[temp, (q5 - q1)/k]], {k, 1, kmax - kmin - 1}
        ];
       
       If[
        Max[temp] < (q2 - q1)/(kmax - kmin),
        AppendTo[pary, {kmin, kmax}]],
       temp = {};
       
       Clear[q5];
       Table[
        q5 = seria[[kmax - k]];
        If[
         q5 > q2,
         AppendTo[temp, (q5 - q2)/k]], {k, 1, kmax - kmin - 1}
        ];
       
       If[
        Max[temp] < (q1 - q2)/(kmax - kmin),
        AppendTo[pary, {kmin, kmax}]
        ]
       
       ]]]],
   {p, 1, n - 1}], {n, 2, lseria}
  (*Label["end1"]*)
  ];
 ]
```

Nest,

```
k = Sort[Join[pary, Map[({#[[2]], #[[1]]}) &, pary]]]
```

The set 'k' contains all the visibility of each peak e.g. peak 'no.2' see the {1, 3, 4, 6, 8} peaks - see fig.1.

On the basis of 'k' we can create a graph:

```
k1 = Map[(#[[1]] \[UndirectedEdge] #[[2]]) &, k];
graph = Graph[k1]
```

The question is: how to recreate the 'series' set on the basis of this graph (set 'k')?
Of course, identical values will not be kept :)

What does 29 see? In the set 'k' there are values for 29: {29, 1}, {29, 8}, {29, 9}, {29, 11}, {29, 12}, {29, 13}, {29, 14}, {29, 15}, {29, 17}, {29, 19}, {29, 20}, {29, 21}, {29, 22}, {29, 23}, {29, 25} . {29, 26}, {29, 27}, {29, 28}, {29, 30}, {29, 31}, {29, 32}, {29, 33}, {29, 46}.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly you are doing. However, k contains 50  different values and your original series only 30. Therefore you must give some criterion how to eliminate superfluous values.

Comment: The code looks hard to follow. What do you mean by visibility?  Do you mean like a landscape / mountains? Why isn't 1 visible from 29?

Comment: ^ if so your code could be highly simplified to create the graph: `lerp[list_] := Subdivide[First[list], Last[list], Length[list] - 1];
visible[heights_] := VectorLessEqual[{heights, lerp[heights]}];
graph = Graph[
  If[visible[seria[[Span @@ #]]], UndirectedEdge @@ #, Nothing] & /@ 
   Subsets[Range[Length[seria]], {2}]]` In general it is not possible to recreate the original landscape based on the visibility graph. It is only possible to create a new landscape that shares the same graph. A trivial example shows that `{1, 1000, 1}` and `{1,2,1}` have the same graph.

Comment: Of course, I am aware that there are many scenarios.  But what, for example, can arise?

Comment: But, set   If[visible[seria[[Span @@ #]]], UndirectedEdge @@ #, Nothing] & /@ 
 Subsets[Range[Length[seria]], {2}]  is different from 'k1'. There is no e.g. 2<->1

Comment: Yes there is - it's the first element 1<->2. You don't need the edge 2<->1 because obviously visibility is undirected. In the graph I showed in my comment, if you add VertexLabels->Automatic, the edge 2<->1 is clearly there. Also what are you asking when you say _But what, for example, can arise?_ ? I was saying you **cannot** reconstruct the original landscape from the graph. You need more information embedded in the graph, possibly using edge weights to encode relative distances.

Comment: I meant one of the reconstruction cases (not oryginal). I was saying  I am aware that there are many scenarios.

Comment: @flinty .  There is a bug in your code. For example, peak 16 sees peak 29.
This is not true.

Comment: @ralph no there is not a bug `ListLinePlot[
 seria, Epilog -> Line[{{16, seria[[16]]}, {29, seria[[29]]}}]
 ]` though we may have a difference of opinion about what visibility means. A line can be drawn from 16 to 29 such that the line is not blocked by a hillside. However I have allowed for the possibility that the line _can_ scrape along an edge of the same gradient. This needs to be true otherwise 2 is not visible from 1.

Comment: @flinty. Ok. Thanks.